# Assembly Code to C

Tags: c, assembly

I was practicing some assembly code to C and need some help with two questions. Based on the GCC objdump it seems okay but I want to make sure I can do this WITHOUT a computer (still kind of new to assembly code)

**Question 1 :**

```
q1:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    subl    $4, %esp
    cmpl    $0, 8(%ebp)\\ compare variable1 to zero
    jle .L2 \\jump if less than or equal to zero
    movl    $1, -4(%ebp)\\ ?? variable2 = 1??
    jmp .L4\\else 
.L2:
    movl    $0, -4(%ebp)\\ variable2 = 0
.L4:
    movl    -4(%ebp), %eax\\ variable2 = variable1
    leave
    ret
```

what I got was

```
int main(int x, int z)  
{
    if (x < 0)
        z = 0;
    else
        z = x;
 }
```

But I was not sure what the purpose of `movl $1, -4(%ebp)` was.

**Question 2 :**

```
fn:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    $1, %eax
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movl    8(%ebp), %edx 
    cmpl    $1, %edx\\ compare variable1 to 1
    jle .L4\\ less than or equal jump.
.L5:
    imull   %edx, %eax\\ multiply variable1 by variable 2
    subl    $1, %edx\\ variable1 -1
    cmpl    $1, %edx\\ compare variable1 with 1
    jne .L5 Loop if not equal
.L4:
    popl    %ebp\\ return value
    ret
```

How I interpreted the information

```
int main(int x)
{
    int result;
    if (x <= 1){
    for (result=1; x != 1; x = x-1)
            result *= x;}
    else{return result;}
}
```

Not sure if my logic is correct on either of those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Q1** you have one argument `8(%ebp)` and one local variable at `-4(%ebp)`. Return value will be in `%eax`. Knowing this, the function looks more like:

```
int foo(int arg)
{
    int local;
    if (arg <= 0) {
        local = 0;
    } else {
        local = 1;
    }
    return local;
}
```

**Q2** `popl %ebp // return value` that's not the return value, that's restoring the saved `%ebp` of the caller (that was pushed in the beginning). <s>Also, the condition in the loop should use `>` not `!=`.</s> You are missing an `if (x > 1)` conditional around the `for` loop. (Thanks to Mooing Duck for pointing this out.) Also, technically it's a `do`-`while` loop. Otherwise you got this function right.

```
int factorial(int x)
{
    int result = 1;
    if (x > 1) {
        do {
            result *= x;
            x -= 1;
        } while(x != 1);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much. DO you think you explain to me why it is not != because I thought 'jne' would make the comparison not equal?

Comment: @user3395013: The for loop condition reads `jne`, the `jle` is actually _inside_ of the loop

Comment: Oh, you are right, it has two conditions. So you need an `if` as well, then.

Comment: The condition in the `for` was okay as `!=`, you need to add the `if` around the `for`, not in the body.

Comment: wouldn't the if statement be `if(x<=1)`?

Comment: @user3395013: no, it _skips_ the body `if(x<=1)`, so it _enters_ the body `if(x>1)`.

Comment: so does `jle` refer to the variable less than or equal to 1 or the other way around because in previous set of code it's switched

Comment: ... this makes me worried if I did the other problems correclty

Comment: wouldn't for question1 also be if `(arg > 0)` because it's `jle`

Comment: Q1 has both branches (it also has an `else`) so it doesn't really matter how you write it as long as the blocks are correct.

Comment: Sorry for all these questions, is the blocks you're referring to is the line of code?

Comment: The stuff between `{ }` is a block

Comment: Oh thank you so much for the explanation, Jester. Really cleared up some of the things I was trying to understand!